# How to implement and tune a LC band-stop filter?

Tags: capacitor, components, filter, layout, inductor

I have designed a simple LC band stop filter with a center frequency of 433MHz. The schematic looks like:

[image: Band-Stop Filter]

The caps are NP0 0603 and the inductors are from the [Coilcraft 0603HP series](http://www.coilcraft.com/0603hp.cfm). The values shown don't give me a center frequency of exactly 433MHz but that's the best I could do with the values available. I figure that I'll need to tune the filter with a spectrum analyzer by substituting different values of capacitors to compensate for the parasitics.

Simulating the exact values yields something like this which isn't quite ideal:

[image: SpiceCircuit]

[image: SpiceSimulation]

My PCB layout looks like:

[image: Layout]

My assumption that I could simply tune this by substituting caps while looking at the response on the spectrum analyzer doesn't seem practical now. I was going to purchase several caps a tenth of a pF apart (ex: 4.5pF, 4.6pF, 4.7pF, 4.8pF, etc) from one another and simply substitute them in. However, I find that I have to buy a reel (and wait 14 weeks) to get the caps I want (0603). For instance, I can only get a 4pF, 4.7pF and a 5pF cap for the series element. Is this the way to tune the filter? If not, how else could it be done? What kind of response should I reasonably expect? Do you see anything wrong with my approach?

Comment: I would suggest that you consider carefully if you can tweak your circuit design some. It is often advisable to use larger values of capacitance (and correspondingly lower inductor values) due to the fact that stray capacitance on a PC board can be similar in value to the small pF range capacitors that you have in your circuit design. LTSpice using the circuit that you show does an ideal solution with out any accounting for stray node-to-node capacitance that may exist on your PCB.

Comment: You call this a band-stop filter, but what frequencies are you trying to pass? On your plot, only frequencies below about 160 MHz pass with less than 10 dB attenuation, so why not just use a low-pass filter?

Comment: @MichaelKaras I had actually initially designed the filter around a 5nH series inductor and then changed it after reading that my trace inductance would be nearly 20nH per inch. Though, I have nothing near an inch, at the time it seemed more substantial than the stray capacitance. As you can see, I am not really experienced with this. I guess the good thing is that with a board in hand I can try different component values (ex: lower inductor value).

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes, I had a similar question. I don't really need to pass anything but DC. The filter is being retrofitted into an existing design due to radiated noise from some switching power supplies. The supplies are shielded but it is suspected that the noise is coupling onto the output as well as the enable lines which exit the shield. So, these traps are being placed just inside the shield. The frequency of interest is mainly 433 MHz. The filter was a suggestion of the manufacturer of the RF module my circuit is interfering with.

Comment: @Jason - Since you are simply trying to pass DC and block high frequencies you should look into using multi layer ferrite bead type components. These simply go in-line with your signals right at the border of your shield / GND plane. These are very inexpensive and small physical surface mount packages lend themselves to PCB use.

Comment: @Jason - Adjusting and trimming a low pass filter to block high frequency RF so that mostly just DC and low frequency gets through is really not necessary. Use a fixed design with a cutoff defined to be at way below the are where you have problematic RF conduction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to fine-tune a capacitor value is to remember that two capacitors in parallel has an equivalent capacitance equal to the sum of the two capacitors. Two capacitors in series has an effect like two resistors in parallel.

Since you're working with single-digit pF capacitors, the second rule is more likely to help you. For example, 4.7 pF in series with 220 pF gives 4.6 pF. 4.7 pF in series with 100 pF gives 4.49 pF, etc.

So if you can afford the space of an extra part in series with each of your capacitors, you can trim up the values by choosing the added series cap.
You can also do this in conjunction with Michael's suggestion of using an adjustable trimmer cap to use a trimmer that varies over a large range to produce just a fine tuning effect in your circuit.

**Edit**

A couple of pieces of advice that you didn't ask about:

1. Before finalizing this design, be sure to simulated it with part parasitics included. On the capacitor side, Kemet and Murata, for example, are very good about providing parasitic models of their parts. Coilcraft also provides [good models](http://www.coilcraft.com/pdf_viewer/showpdf.cfm?f=pdf_store%3aspice_0603hp.pdf) for the part family you mentioned.

   A little bit of parasitic resistance might actually help your design by broadening out the deepest notches, so making the performance at the target frequency less sensitive to part variation.
2. If parasitic resistance doesn't broaden out your notch enough to save you sensitivity hassles, consider deliberately adding some small series resistors for this purpose.
3. Before you finalize the design, be sure to do at least some tolerance analysis. For each capacitor and inductor, do another simulation run with its value adjusted to the maximum or minimum of its tolerance range, depending which you think will mess up the circuit more. If you don't know which is worse, try both.

   If you have access to a tool that provides it, you can tell it the tolerances of each part and it will do a *Monte Carlo analysis*, meaning hundreds of runs with the values varied randomly each time to let you see the statistical variation of the notch depth, Q-factor, etc.
4. I was going to mention that for a simulation like you did to give accurate results, you need to simulate it with the actual source and load equivalent resistances it will see in the real circuit, but I see you already did that. For future readers: Don't simulate a filter in a 50 Ohm circuit and expect it to have the same response in a power-supply application with a 1-Ohm load.

   In this line I will mention that power supplies are tricky. The 1-Ohm source and 10-Ohm load you simulated are probably W.A.G.'s at best, especially for the 430 MHz you care most about. If the signal you want to block is actually a conducted emission you want to keep from getting *off* your board, and it comes from digital switching noise, it might be more accurate to model it as a high-impedance current source, rather than the low-impedance voltage source you used.

   Uncertainty about the source and load impedance is likely to be a more important source of inaccuracy in your simulation than the layout parasitics.
5. Testing this circuit will require some thought. For the same reason you can't simulate the filter in a 50-Ohm system and expect it to perform the same in 10-Ohm system, you can't test it with a 50-Ohm source and load and expect the measurement to reflect the real performance.

   Of course you can do some reflection measurements to improve your guesses about the source and load impedances (on a board with the filter components un-stuffed). And it might be possible to do some careful math and transform the results of a 50-Ohm test to give the performance in the real system.

   Alternately, on the load side, probing with a low-capacitance 'scope probe (if it has enough bandwidth) will probably give you a more accurate view than connecting through the 50-Ohm coax connections implied by your schematic. Not that the coax connector footprint you drew wouldn't make a reasonable probe test points if you just leave the connectors unstuffed.

I'm assuming this circuit is for a production run of more than 5 units (and it could be 100's, 1000's, or more), because for a one-off you could probably get away with just solder-tacking it out on/over a blank clad board and tweaking it until it works, and save the time and expense of fabbing a PWB.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed response! I elected to go with caps in series as opposed to a trimmer. I don't want to add a tuning step to the production process.

Comment: Also, regarding your 'why not low pass' comment. The only answer I can come up with as to why they insist on a band-stop filter is that I am getting much more attenuation (in that band) than I can achieve with a simple low pass. I am basing that on simulations only.

Comment: @Jason, Given you have a single-frequency interference(?) source you need to filter out, a notch filter makes sense. But if you really need, say, better than 50 dB attenuation at that frequency, you will really need to do the tolerance analysis I mentioned in the "extra advice" section I added to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

A very common method to be used for fine tuning a filter is to utilize a component called a trimmer capacitor. These are best used in parallel with an existing capacitor in your circuit. The trimmer range is selected so that parallel total capacitance of the trimmer plus the fixed capacitor gets your total just right.

Here is a typical surface mounted trimmer.

[image]

Mouser offers [one like the above](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Murata/TZB4Z060AA10B00/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMukHu%252bjC5l7YT0yqY1dqUnriglrvsy4Cv8=) as a variable ~2pF to ~6pF for 1.33$ US.

Comment: $1.33 each... ouch!

Comment: Can't you also get trimmer inductors?

Comment: @Rocketmagnet - You can get tunable inductors but in my experience they tend to be quite a bit larger.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for basic RF filtering of signal lines and power rails, where high frequencies are involved, is to use ferrite bead type components. Put them in series with your signal paths and power connections. There are many sources for these but one manufacturer that I use all the time is Murata. You can find many parts at Mouser (http://www.mouser.com) if you look under "EMI Filter Beads". These will typically be rated at some low impedance at DC with a significant increase in impedance at high frequency RF. Use care to select a component that is rated at a current level above the amount of current that you expect to run through the part.

For example here is a part that is 0805 size, capable of 200 mA and has a DC resistance of 0.6 ohms. At RF frequencies the impedance goes up to 2.2K ohms.

http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Murata/BLM21BD222TH1D/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtoiMfofRG0Ledi9m9QXz4zE7J1sKlCQ08%3d

The data sheet shows the impedance / frequency curve for this family of parts as:
[image]